# unnamed module problem with a library in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a ray casting light intellij project in javafx with gradle that im trying to add soft shadows to, and i wish to use the GPU to help. I decided to use Aparapi to do so, as i can write code in pure java. the problem im coming up with is that after adding this to my dependencies in my build file:

```
implementation "com.aparapi:aparapi:3.0.0"
```

and this in my module-info file:

```
requires static aparapi.jni;
requires static aparapi;
```

i get this error stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.example.ray_casting.ImageKernel (in module com.example.ray_casting) cannot access class com.aparapi.Kernel (in unnamed module @0x52c51a06) because module com.example.ray_casting does not read unnamed module @0x52c51a06
    at com.example.ray_casting/com.example.ray_casting.Update.updateShadows(Update.java:84)
    at com.example.ray_casting/com.example.ray_casting.Update.handle(Update.java:64)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/javafx.animation.AnimationTimer$AnimationTimerReceiver.lambda$handle$0(AnimationTimer.java:58)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/javafx.animation.AnimationTimer$AnimationTimerReceiver.handle(AnimationTimer.java:57)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractPrimaryTimer.timePulseImpl(AbstractPrimaryTimer.java:356)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractPrimaryTimer$MainLoop.run(AbstractPrimaryTimer.java:266)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:571)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:555)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:548)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:352)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
```

i tried doing some googling to figure out why as im not familiar with adding additional libraries/frameworks/whatever-aparapi-is to projects, and from what i understand if im not wrong is that Gradle puts aparapi on the classpath instead of the modulepath, with the classpath then being treated as the module. Am i just stuck or is there a way around this?